# docker volume mounts with cached option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Does adding `:cached` on a volume mount for mac performance tuning effect docker for windows volume mounts?

I'm working on a team with both mac and windows machines and it seems to still work but want to see if anyone has more to add on this.

Here is the docker docs link https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/

But they don't say thing about how it effects windows?

An example they give in their docs.

```
docker run -v /Users/yallop/project:/project:cached alpine command
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may only have an effect on mac。
[detail](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-mount-consistency-for-macos)

Comment: Nice, thats it. `These options are completely ignored on all host operating systems except macOS.` From that link. Thank you!

Comment: The link no longer has any mentions of `cached`. In fact I am searching for docs on this option for a lot of time now. Did it go deprecated?

Answer (score 8):

`:delegated` and `:cached` flags are redundant since Docker Desktop 2.4.0.0 where gRPC FUSE file sharing is used by default.

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5402