# vs code dev container : docker volumes mount with cached option on macos

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to build a develop environment with the visual code dev container extension. I use MacBook.
the default generated docker-compose in the vs code .devcontainer foler
use

```
volumes:
      # Update this to wherever you want VS Code to mount the folder of your project
      - .:/workspace:cached
```

A similar question was answer by [docker volume mounts with cached option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120722/docker-volume-mounts-with-cached-option), but the docker doc remove that the words about the cached option now.
Dose it mean now the cached option has no effect on all os?
If so, why the vs code need to use  this cached option?